ortools CVRP soft constraint on route distance
I am using Google ortools for CVRP. I have constraints on both vehicle capacity and max distance (in reality, it's a max travel time constraint, but I'm formulating it as a distance constraint). Both constraints are holding. The issue is that my max travel time constraint, in real life, is a goal: at least XX% of routes under the maximum time. So I don't need 100% of the routes to meet this constraint, but X% - and in fact, if 100% of the routes were under it then that may be suboptimal for the business.
Is there a way to express this goal in ortools or do I just need to fiddle around with the max time constraint and hope for the best?

Of the top of my head I am not sure how to express the x% of routes being less than the limit in OR-Tools.
That said you could make it a SoftUpperBound where it is penalized each time it goes above.
        time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time_dimension_name) 
   
        for vehicle_id in range(data["num_vehicles"]):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        route_time_limit.SetCumulVarSoftLowerBound(
            routing.End(vehicle_id), 
            MAX_ROUTE_TIME_LIMIT,
            PENALTY,
            )


Right now I have a hard upper bound on travel time using the distance dimension (my distance matrix is actually a time matrix). How would I apply this SoftUpperBound to the distance matrix instead?

Just change all the parts assosciated to time and replace with distance. As a side note, this can be used with almost anything else. For example, you can use this to limit the number of customers visited per trip or the total quantity delivered and so on.
